# Ring of formal power series over a principal ideal domain is a unique factorisation domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, noetherian, unique-factorization-domains

An exercise in my algebra course book asks to prove that if $R$ is a [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), then $R[[x]]$ is a [UFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), where $R[[x]]$ is the ring of formal power series over $R$.
After some failed attempts at  proving the [ACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition_on_principal_ideals) I visited Wikipedia, which [comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Algebraic_properties_of_the_formal_power_series_ring):

> If $R$ is Noetherian, then so is $R[[x]]$; this is a version of the Hilbert basis theorem.

This is very useful, as $R$ is a PID and hence Noetherian. Unfortunately we only saw (without proof) Hilbert's basis theorem in the form

> If $R$ is Noetherian, then so is $R[x]$.

I'm not sure how to conclude the Noetherianity of $R[[x]]$ from this. I know that $R[x]$ is a UFD because $R$ is (we saw this without proof), and have been trying to conclude the ACC in $R[[x]]$ from the ACC in $R[x]$, without success.
I can prove the ACC if $R$ is a field, because then every $a_kx^k+a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+\cdots$ with $a_k\neq0$ is associate with $x^k$, hence every ideal is of the form $(x^k)$. (In fact this readily proves that $R[[x]]$ is a UFD.) If $R$ is not a field, say it has some non-invertible element $r$, then there are many more ideals such as $(r)$ or $(r+x)$.

I'm also facing difficulties at identifying the irreducible elements of $R[[x]]$. (I wish to prove that they are all primes in order to conclude the uniqueness of factorisation.) I have figured that they either take the form $ux+Px^2$ for some unit $u\in R^\times$ and some $P\in R[[x]]$ or have a non-zero constant term which is not invertible in $R$. The elements of the form $ux+Px^2$ are indeed primes, the difficulty lies in those with non-zero constant term.

Any hints at proving $R[[x]]$ is a UFD?

Comment: You can prove that if $R$ is noetherian, then $R[[x]]$ is noetherian using the same strategy that one would use to prove the Hilbert basis theorem (of which there is a fairly short proof in Atiyah & MacDonald's "Commutative Algebra").

Comment: I don't think we're supposed to do it that way because we didn't see a proof of Hilbert's basis theorem. There should be another way.

Comment: Have you found an irreducible in $\Bbb Z[[x]]$ that’s not a unit times an irreducible from $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: @Lubin Interesting question. I haven't yet. Proving this would show the ACC.

Comment: In fact we dont _have_ to find them all, we only have to show that every irreducible is prime.

Answer (score 5):

Another answer to the problem given by the OP:

> If $R$ is a PID, then $R[[X]]$ is a UFD.

The key to prove the above result is to use a theorem known as [Kaplansky's criterion for UFDs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160207082313/http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math581Fall2012/Kaplansky.pdf):

> **Theorem:** An integral domain $D$ is a UFD if only if every nonzero prime ideal of $D$ contains a prime element.

I'm not going to write all the details because I don't want to write a long post. In order to use Kaplansky's criterion we need the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $A$ be a commutative unitary ring. Let $\phi\colon A[[X]]\rightarrow A$ be the map given by $$f=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iX^i\mapsto a_0.$$ Then $\phi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. Moreover if $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime ideal of $A[[X]]$, then $\mathfrak{P}$ is finitely generated in $A[[X]]$ if only if $\phi(\mathfrak{P})$ is finitely generated in $A$.

A proof of the above lemma can be found in Sharp's book "*Steps in Commutative Algebra*" or in Watkins' book "*Topics in Commutative Ring Theory*". In such proofs it's shown the following:

> If $X\in \mathfrak{P}$, then $\mathfrak{P}$ is generated by the same elements that generate $\phi(\mathfrak{P})$ plus $X$; and if $X\notin \mathfrak{P}$, then the number of generators of $\mathfrak{P}$ is the same as that of $\phi(\mathfrak{P})$.

Finally, to prove the theorem given at the beginning of the post we proceed as follows. We first note that $X$ is a prime element of $R[[X]]$. Next, given a nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$, if $X\in \mathfrak{P}$, then $\mathfrak{P}$ contains the prime element $X$. Otherwise, by the lemma $\mathfrak{P}$ is f.g. with the same number of generators as the ideal $\phi(\mathfrak{P})$, but $R$ being a PID implies that $\phi(\mathfrak{P})$ is principal, so $\mathfrak{P}$ is principal too, i.e., there is some $f\in R[[X]]$ such that $\mathfrak{P}=(f)$. Since $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime ideal is easy to see that $f$ is a prime element, so $\mathfrak{P}$ contains the prime $f$. Hence, by Kaplansky's criterion $R[[X]]$ is a UFD.

As a side remark, the lemma that we've used is also applied (together with Cohen's theorem) to prove the analogue of Hilbert basis' theorem for formal power series.

Comment: In your text you state a lemma proved in a book by Sharp and a book by Watkins. Unfortunately I do not have access to these books. I would be grateful if you could give me at least one of their proofs. Thank you in advance. RC

Answer (score 3):

The set of irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ is not known, and is more complicated as it seems.

You might find some interesting families of irreducible elements in this paper :

http://www.ijma.info/index.php/ijma/article/view/2357

However, it does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $R[[X]]$ is a UFD you can use Theorem 20.3 in Commutative Ring Theory by Matsumura which states that if $A$ is a regular UFD so is $A[[X]]$ and show that every PID is regular which is rather easy.

See also this paper:
http://people.brandeis.edu/~buchsbau/miscpapers/10052.pdf

Comment: Given that the OP has not even seen the proof the Hilbert's  basis theorem, using the concept of regularity is quite likely to not be helpful...