# Determining ring type for the formal series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

Given the following set of rings:

$$\mathcal{C} = \{\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}], \ \mathbb{Z}[X], \ \mathbb{Z}, \ \mathbb{Q}
, \ \mathbb{Q}[X]\}$$

I am told to determine, $\forall S\in\mathcal{C}$ what type of ring the formal series of $S$, $(S[[X]],+,\cdot)$, is. That is, is it a field? An euclidean domain? Ideal principal domain? UFD?

Any help with this question would be apreciated!

Comment: $1.$ You wrote twice $\Bbb Q[X]$ ; $2.$ I think you mean "Euclidean" instead of eulerian ; $3.$ What are your thoughts?

Comment: @DietrichBurde : what does $\Bbb Z [[i\sqrt 3]]$ mean? Shouldn't it be $\Bbb Z[i \sqrt 3][[X]]$ instead?

Comment: @Watson Sorry, I got confused. It is $\mathbb{Q}[x][[X]]$ then, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde : I don't know, but I would say $\Bbb Q[x][[y]]$.

Comment: Yes, one of them is only $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Also, you are right, $\mathbb{Q}[X][[Y]]$, $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}][[X]]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X][[Y]]$ are the coresponding rings of formal series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All above power series rings have been studied at MSE. For example, $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ is a unique factorization domain, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096521/ring-of-formal-power-series-over-a-principal-ideal-domain-is-a-unique-factorisat), and is a $2$-dimensional regular Noetherian domain,
but not a PID, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field (for $K[[X]]$ with a field $K$ it is a PID, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644468/ring-of-formal-power-series-over-a-field-is-a-principal-ideal-domain)). Hence it is not Euclidean as well.

Comment: What is MSE? What does it stand for?

Comment: MSE stands for "Mathematics Stackexchange".